# Elasticsearch completion suggester, custom ordering

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

Is there a way to achieve custom ordering in the Elasticsearch feature "Completion suggester" without providing a separate field containing a "weight" attribute during indexing?

My goal is to sort the suggestions on string length (or similar relevance), so that short words is scored higher than longer words.

Here is a mapping example of a field I want to provide autocomplete function on:

```
...
skills: {
  type: "nested", 
  include_in_parent: true, 
  properties: {            
    name: {
      type: "multi_field",
      fields: {
        name: {type: "string"},
        original: {type : "string", analyzer : "string_lowercase", include_in_all : false},                   
        suggest: {type: "completion", index_analyzer: "simple", search_analyzer: "simple"}
      }              
    }
  }
}
...
```

Here I provide several different fields, the "original" field is for filtering in queries, the "suggest" field is used for the completion suggester.

My data when indexing could look like this:

```
...
"skills": [
  {
     "name": "C",
     "source": [
        "linkedin"
     ]
  },
  {
     "name": "Computer Science",
     "source": [
        "stackoverflow"
     ]
  },
]
...
```

What I'm trying to avoid is having to provide an extra field when indexing and add weighting for this myself, like this:

```
...
"skills_suggest": [
  {
    "input": ["C"],
    "output": "C",
    "weight" : 100
  },
  {
    "input": ["Computer Science"],
    "output": "Computer Science",
    "weight" : 50
  }
]
...
```

I'm trying to do this because I use a autocomplete function on a searchfield in my application. I show the 10 highest hits in a dropdown below the searchfield. My problem is when I have so many skills to choose from, that when I type in the letter "C", the actual skill that is the programming language "C" is scored lower than longer words and therefore is not showing up in my dropdown top 10.